# Having an issue while trying to implement In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, cocoa, in-app-purchase

This is my first time to implement In-App purchase and I am using the tutorial located here: [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Now I am sure this is something simple, but I am having issues figuring out, so I figured I would ask all of the gurus out here.

The compiler is saying that _products is Use of undeclared identifier

```
 - (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {

 NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
 [_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
 if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {



 *stop = YES;
 }
 }];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this post http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/ They teach how to implment in app purchases even teach out to get other users to test that app...

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a simple mistake.  Most issues are and we all fall victim to them every once in while.

```
NSArray *_products;
```

That little line of code fixed the errors that I was having.